# How to have a field in Postgresql depending on the previous rows found?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, select

To make it simple, I have a table with stock in/out like this :

```
date,in_out
2013-08-05,+5
2013-08-07,-2
2013-08-12,-1
```

What I would like to do is to have the number of items in stock for each date :

```
date,in_out,quantity
2013-08-05,+5,5
2013-08-07,-2,3
2013-08-12,-1,2
```

But even if I normally know Postgresql quite well I really don't see how to write a SELECT request that could take into account previous rows.

What I would have done is something like that :

```
SELECT date,in_out, (stock_quant := stock_quant + in_out) AS quantity FROM table_stock;
```

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are looking for a running sum:

```
select date,
       in_out,
       quantity,
       sum(quantity) over (order by date) as quantity
from  table_stock
order by date;
```

Btw: `date` is a horrible name for a column. First it's also a reserved word and secondly it doesn't document what the column contains. A "start date", an "end date", a "change date", ...

Comment: Thank you very much ! And don't worry, all the names I used here are fake, my tables are anyway more complex and what I need to do is a stock prevision in the future which is quite different, but I searched for a case that would be more simple to explain, and thanks again a lot I didn't know about running sums at all until now :-)

Comment: Just a question, is there a way to do a running sum before Postgres 8.4 ? Because window/over was only introduced in 8.4 AFAIK ?

Comment: I found some interesting link : http://www.depesz.com/2007/08/17/rownum-anyone-cumulative-sum-in-one-query/

Comment: @DenisBUCHER: not possible in earlier versions - and anything before 8.4 isn't supported any longer. So you should migrate to a supported version anyway.

Comment: Yes, but having our complete datawarehouse on 8.3 makes it a huge work and some kind of risk to migrate everything, not sure it is worth doing it already...

Comment: @DenisBUCHER: the longer you wait, the painfuller the migration will be. Nnow you only need to jump 4 versions. If you wait longer it will be 5, then 6 and each time it will get harder.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
SELECT date,in_out, stock_quant + in_out AS quantity 
FROM table_stock;
```

Comment: There is no column `stock_quant` in table `table_stock`.

Answer (score 0):

Great I found a solution for Postgres 8.3 and earlier version :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION hds_csum_init() 
    RETURNS void 
    LANGUAGE plperl AS
$hds_csum_init$
    $_SHARED{csum} = 0;
$hds_csum_init$;
```

and

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION hds_csum_sum(integer) 
    RETURNS integer
    LANGUAGE plperl AS
$hds_csum_sum$
    my $observation = shift;
    return $_SHARED{csum} += $observation;
$hds_csum_sum$;
```

and then :

```
SELECT hds_csum_init() ;
SELECT *, hds_csum_sum(in_out::integer) AS quantity FROM (SELECT * FROM table_stock);
```

And it works great !